# Synchronous video recording from two iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video, synchronization

Do I have the possibility to synchronize one action on two iPhones programmatically? In my case: I push record video button at one iPhone and it starts to record not only at this, but also at second iPhone simultaneously and so on. Doesn't it brakes some Apple rules for making apps and is it generally possible? Now I even can't imagine main logic of way it can be done.

Thanks for any advance!

Comment: What would be the case if device is password locked?

Comment: Now I watch to this https://github.com/danieldickison/CocoaOSC ,but not sure that the possibility to connect devices via UDP can helps me to synchronize actions

Comment: Minkle Garg, user will interested to prevent this for using main app functional,because it's a bit specific. But it's an interesting question, I need to think about it, thanks!

Comment: That can be done using bonjour webservice [Check tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) and also [Source code available](http://www.mobileorchard.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/chatty.zip). Go on exploring [see this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-camera-wirelessly-connect/id374351996?mt=8) it does something you required with some modification.

Comment: let u look upon bump api